# Cannot write to file with write permission

Tags: permissions

I have this file:

```
$ ls -lrta ~/.bash_profile
-rwxr-x---. 1 xxx xxx 904 May 23 15:36 /home/xxx/.bash_profile
$
```

I am the owner of the file and I have write permission.
When I try to edit (delete the last line for example) the file I got an error,

```
$ sed -i '$ d' .bash_profile
sed: cannot rename ./sedxkZezg: Operation not permitted
$
```

Appending a text using cat can successfully write to file.

```
$ cat >> .bash_profile
  writing
  ^D
$
```

I viewed the appended text like this,

```
$ cat .bash_profile
... <some text> ...
writing
$
```

Error also occurs when I edit the file using a text editor (vi).

Can anyone explain why can't I write the file though I have a write permission?

Here is some information of the system I'm using:

```
$ uname -svr
Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012
```

**UPDATE**:

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$ sed -i '$ d' .bash_profile > file && mv file .bash_profile
sed: cannot rename ./sedm89Ym2: Operation not permitted

$ lsattr ~/.bash_profile
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /home/xxx/.bash_profile

$ getfact ~/.bash_profile
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: xxx/xxx/.bash_profile
# owner: xxx
# group: xxx
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
$
```

Comment: Any log about it?

Comment: Sorry, I have no root access so I can't provide some logs right now.

Answer (score 4):

The '.' at the end of the `ls` permissions output says there are extended data of some kind. `chattr(1)` gives the list of attributes for ext? file systems, `lsattr(1)` lists the current ones. Also check tha ACL for the file (`getfacl(1)`). A security policy (like SELinux) could also forbid some operations on the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i ... file
```

actually does something like:

```
sed ... file > some-temp-file &&
  mv some-temp-file file
```

That last `mv` does a `rename`. That is `sed -i` doesn't edit the file in place, it replaces it with a modified copy of itself.

Here it's the rename that is blocked. It is not blocked because of permission issues (you'd get a *permission denied* error message if it was), but it looks like there's some administrative restriction either to unlink the inode of your ~/.bash_profile (like some SELinux type of mandatory access control), or to the path to that file (like some AppArmor type MAC).

You can probably find more clue somewhere in the logs.

```
getfattr -dm- ~/.bash_profile
```

would list all the extended attributes (ACLs, security contexts) of the file.

```
lsattr ~/.bash_profile
```

for potentially more Linux attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you dont have write permission of parent dir (which is weird because its your home)

Anyway, can you do:

```
$ ls -la ~
```

Comment: If he didn't, sed wouldn't have been able to create the ./sedxkZezg file. And the error would be EACCESS, not EPERM. Sounds more like some SELinux issue.